# LINQ distinct is showing duplicates

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to use LINQ to find duplicates. From what I have read, I should use `distinct`. The query below finds the duplicates in the list, but it contains both the original value and its duplicate.

How can I get only the distinct items?

```
Class MacroConfig
{

    public Guid? GUID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

//This is the linq query I am using
List<MacroConfig> dupeList = macroListWithDuplicates.GroupBy(x => x.GUID)
    .Where(y => y.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(y => y)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

foreach (var x in dupeList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
}
```

Comment: `Distinct` based on what property `GUID` or all others as well ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Distinct() will return distinct MacroConfig objects, because MacroConfig's is what distinct() is receiving as input.
If you only want to get 1 item for each GUID, you can just select the first item from each group:

```
List<MacroConfig> dupeList = macroListWithDuplicates
.GroupBy(x => x.GUID)
.Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)
.Select(grp => grp.First())
.ToList();
```

Comment: +1, your answer made it clear that the OP was actually looking for those distinct items which have  a duplicate present.

Comment: @Habib Too bad the OP didn't make that clear. The rest of us might have answered differently.

Answer (score 1):

```
var unique = from p in macroListWithDuplicates
                   group p by new {p.GUID } 
                   into mygroup
                   select mygroup.First();
```

Comment: Why not simply "group p by p.GUID"? No need for an anonymous type.

Answer (score 1):

How do you define a duplicate?

Distinct...

> Returns distinct elements from a sequence by using the default equality comparer to compare values.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Have a look at the DistinctBy() operator in the [MoreLinq](http://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) NuGet package.

DistinctBy allows you to easily define exactly what constitutes a distinct entity.

Comment: an XElement with the same GUID attribute value

Comment: Distinct looks at the default equality comparer, which does not look at your properties.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
List<MacroConfig> dupeList = macroListWithDuplicates.GroupBy(x => x.GUID)
    .Select(y => y.First())
    .ToList();
```